# Filtering content from parsed HTML with htmlagilitypack in C#

Tags: c#, filtering, html-agility-pack

I'm having trouble filtering the correct data from a HMTL document, I dont know how to continue.

Basically I need to store data that is in between /h3 and h3 tags, so every paragraph and html code in between. For example, I have this method printing all the headers:

```
    static void Printheaders()
    // gives headers
    {
        HtmlDocument voorbeeld = new HtmlDocument();
        string path = "voorbeeld.html";
        voorbeeld.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        voorbeeld.Load(path);

        var test = voorbeeld.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3");

        int c = 0;
        string[] s = new string[test.Count()];


        foreach (var a in test)
        {
            s[c] = a.InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine("Naam hoofdstuk: " + s[c]);
            c++;

        }
```

I want the corresponding code following the headers up to the next header printed per header. My current code basically prints me a list with ''Naam hoofdstuk: '' + ''header name''.
How do I select the data in between all the headers though, there are many paragraphs in the html file between every header, and selecting the nodes with //p does not provide me with the desired result.

EDIT:
To add, so my question is, can HtmlAgilityPack parse elements between the end of one particular html tag and the start of another html tag, rather than something within the tag!